# How to fail when record not found using ActiveRecord where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When using `#find` an exception is raised when a record is not found, how do I get the same effect using `#where`?

I want to fetch a number of records by the `key` attribute and fail if any are missing. The key attribute is unique.

```
keys = %w(apple pear grape)
fruits = Fruit.where(key: keys)
```

This could return between 0 and 3 records.

I want this to fail unless 3 records are returned.

Is it possible to do this within ActiveRecord or do I need to check the `size` of the returned collection as such:

```
fruits = Fruit.where(key: keys).tap { |fruits| raise(...) unless fruits.size == keys.size }
```

Comment: What kind of failure would be that? Have you considered using `having` and `exists?`? Something like `Fruit.having('count(*) = 3').exists?(key: keys)` would be a predicate, wouldn't raise any error.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Interesting. I get an SQL error for this, but would it involve two queries, as I need the records, not just to check a certain number exist (I've updated the question to make this clearer).

Comment: 5 up votes and 2 down votes.

Answer (score 1):

The where method is designed to mirror SQL's where clause, so it will not fail if no matching records are found. It'll just return an empty relation.

After you have filtered your records, raise an error if the size of the returned relation is not equal to what you're looking for. You need to do this before looping through any returned records

```
keys = %w(apple pear grape)
fruits = Fruit.where(key: keys)
raise 'my special error' unless fruits.size == keys.length
# loop here
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is essentially the same as the solution I propose in the answer. I was wondering if there was an ActiveRecord method which would enforce this constraint, that the count of records was equal to the count of keys.

Comment: There is no method I know of that will do that. You could monkey patch a method onto the ActiveRecord class so that's it's available throughout your project. Other options would be to create a module or if the method is only invoked by controllers, you can define it in application_controller.